# Using Ajax to call php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I'm building a forgot password system, and I would like the Forgot Password div to execute the forgotpassword php script when it is clicked.
Note: all files are in the same directory
I so far have:
In HTML

```
<div id="forgotpass" href="" onclick="fpass()">forgot your password?</div>
```

In my Javascript file:

```
function fpass() {
console.log("fpass function");
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'forgotpass.php',
       success: function(data){
            //data returned from php
            //console.log(data);
       }
    });
}
```

Inside the php script I have a few echo statements so far to test if the script actually gets run.

However, when I click "forgot your password?" it runs fpass() and alerts "fpass function" so I know the function works. But I don't think its executing the php script. I'm new to this so can anyone provide me an explanation as to why the php script isn't getting executed. Do I need to put anything inside the php script?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you commenting out the //alert(data); this would give you a better indication if it completing, also use the developers tools(F12) to monitor the traffic.

Comment: If your PHP expects a post request, it could simply be skipping over and returning nothing. use console.log to debug, not alert!

Comment: Uncomment the alert and add an `error` function that is the same as the `success` (i.e. has an alert) so you can see what's going on. Also, this Ajax call is pointless without sending parameters, so add some.

Comment: "`Do I need to put anything inside the php script?`" Yes, make it print something so your `alert(data);` will have something to alert you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending any data add

```
data    : form.serialize()
```

In php you can catch your data's with

```
$_POST['data_name']
```

And this is a better convension for your code.

```
        $.ajax({
            type    : 'POST',
            url     : 'forgotpass.php',
            data    :  form.serialize()
        }).done(function(data){
            if(data['success']){

            }else{

            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Would 'data' be the name of the data in $_POST['data_name']?

Comment: data_name is your input's name field. such as <input type="text" name="mete">, and data_name is mete in here.

Comment: But what if its a div?
<div id="forgotpass" href="" onclick="fpass()">forgot your password?</div>
what would the data_name be?